# PHP PhantomJs - клик на элемент

Tags: phantomjs

Доброе время суток, перерыл весь http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/ 
Но не могу найти как кликнуть на элемент на странице в PhantomJs 
Вообщем мне надо кликнуть на элемент на странице как это сделать? 
Есть у когонибуть пример или хотя бы ссылка на адеватную документацию с примерами?

Comment: Вот пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948355

Comment: Тоесть стандартными средствами PHP PhantomJs это ни как не сделать? придется вертеть кастыли на JS